# Anchor tag onClick is not working ajax using laravel 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

On my page one anchor tag is their for that anchor tag i have assigned one class named as state when i clicks on anchor tag it's not redirecting on desired page , In console i have seen my query is working. Here is my ajax

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('a.state').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var link = $(this).attr('id');
    //alert(link); 
        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: 'property_details/{state}',
           dataType: "json",
           data: {id: link}
        });
 });
});
</script>
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('property_details/{state}', array('as' => 'property_details', 'uses' => 'PageController@property_details'));
```

this is my controller

```
  public function property_details() {
    $filter = Input::get('id');
    $view = DB::table('property_details')
    ->leftJoin('agent_registration_details','property_details.state', '=', 'agent_registration_details.state')
    ->where('property_details.state', 'LIKE', '%' . $filter . '%')
    ->get();
        //return Response::json($view);
          //var_dump($view);
        return View::make('pages/property_details', array('row'=>$view));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changin your url to

```
url: "{{url('property_details')}}/"+link,
```

and controller to

```
public function property_details($filter) {
    $view = DB::table('property_details')
    ->leftJoin('agent_registration_details','property_details.state', '=', 'agent_registration_details.state')
    ->where('property_details.state', 'LIKE', '%' . $filter . '%')
    ->get();
        //return Response::json($view);
          //var_dump($view);
        return View::make('pages/property_details', array('row'=>$view));
    }
```

or:

```
url: 'property_details',
```

route

```
Route::get('property_details', array('as' => 'property_details', 'uses' => 'PageController@property_details'));
```

Note: if you are using `dataType: "json"` return json if not remove it

Note2: you need a success function in your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "{{url('property_details')}}",
           dataType: "json",
           data: {id: link}
           success:function(data){
             $('body').append(data);//you may change this
           }
        });
```

Comment: Hi i have tried as per your suggestion but it's not working!. thanks

Comment: what does your console display?

Comment: {"id":1,"sale_or_rent":"rent","property_type":"Single_Family_Home","property_room":"1","property_baths":"1","property_size":"1000","property_garage":"1","property_year":"03\/11\/2008","property_floor":"10","sale_by":"owner","property_price":"10000","phonenumber":"9655235795","address":"Birmingham, AL, United States","lat":"33.5206608","log":"-86.80248999999998","state":"Alabama","city":"Birmingham"} this is my console is displaying, i am getting the correct result but my link is not working

Comment: what link are you talking about??

Comment: Better question what is the link suppose to do ?

Comment: <a href="{{URL::to('property_details', array('id'=>$value->state)) }}" id="{{$value->state}}"  class="state">more details</a> this is my link when i am selected the state particular state come from on next page but my  console  is coming

Comment: why do you need ajax if you want to redirect to next page?

Comment: ok let me explain I have three properties named as Alabama, Arizona, Alaska when i clicked Alabama then i filtering the data related to alabama after that showing results on next page right now my url is coming like this http://localhost/realestate-site/public/property_details  but i want my url will look like this    http://localhost/realestate-site/public/property_details?id=Alaska how can i do like this thanks in advance...

Comment: try `<a href="{{URL::to('property_details')) }?id={{$value->state}}" class="state">more details</a>` ,note route has to be `Route::get('property_details',...`